# The special unitary group is a Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups

I am trying to find a proof of the fact that the special unitary group is a Lie Group, but I can't come up with any good ideas and I couldn't find anything by searching at google.

Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could show that it is a sub manifold of the collection of all $n \times n$ matrices by showing that 0 is the only critical value of the determinant.

Comment: @Wintermute: That argument would work for $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb C)$, but the OP asked about $\operatorname{SU}(n)$.

Comment: Any ideas, please?